# GNU screen dynamic title

Tags: gnu-screen, zshrc, screenrc

I have a setting that works on one computer (Linux mint 18.3 sylvia) and not on another one (Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS) and I don't really know what to check to find the problem :

I'm using GNU screen and I put the name of each window, which change dynamically while I'm changing directory or running a task.

for example if I prompt `cd ~/desktop` it will show `~/desktop cd ~/desktop`. if then I prompt `cd ..` it will show `~ cd ..`.

the problem is, on the second computer, it doesn't work, or rather, it half work, but I don't understand how.

here is how the config should work : one part is in the .screenrc file and the other part in the .zshrc file.

*.screnrc :*

```
hardstatus string "%{= KW}%n %t %=%c %D %d-%m-%y"
```

`%t` is the part for title, and should be expand with PATH_SPACE_STRING

it works thanks to what I put in the .zshrc file, which make the shell to output a title escape sequence (esc k title esc ) as asked here https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Dynamic-Titles.html

*.zshrc :*

```
preexec () {                                                               
 if [[ $TERM == screen* ]]; then                                           
   print -Pn '\ek%~ $1\e\\'                                            
 fi                                                                        
}
```

where `%~` stand for the current path, and `$1` is the string typed in the prompt

but after several tests, I understand that the computer running Ubuntu does not listen to what I put inside the .zshrc file, but it expand anyway the `%t` into the path (so I've got the path as a title, and not the path plus the prompt command)

what can give screen the instruction of dynamically put the current path as a title, if not what I wrote in the .zshrc file? and how to overwrite it?